# How can I loop through the coordinates of a CGPath?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uibezierpath

Im trying make a sprite follow a circular path when the user moves their finger over it, not an animation but instead like a spinning wheel where you can control the direction and speed... any idea would be very useful. thanks

```
let blueDotCategoryName = "blue"
var blueDot = SKSpriteNode()

//...    

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
/* Called when a touch begins */
let touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
let node = self.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation)
if node.name == blueDotCategoryName {
    fingerIsOn = true
}
}



override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
if fingerIsOn {
    let touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
    let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
    let prevTouchLocation = touch.previousLocationInNode(self)
    let blueDot = self.childNodeWithName(blueDotCategoryName) as     SKSpriteNode
   // var newPosition = coordinates in circle UIBezierPath
   // blueDot.position = ...
}
/*        
var circle = UIBezierPath()
circle.addArcWithCenter(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), radius: (self.frame.width / 6.7), startAngle: 0, endAngle: 360, clockwise: true)       
*/

}
override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
fingerIsOn = false
}
```

Comment: no, I mean it rotates over a circular path that I already defined                                                             `var circle = UIBezierPath()                              circle.addArcWithCenter(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), radius: (self.frame.width / 6.7), startAngle: 0, endAngle: 360, clockwise: true)`                                                            like an orbit

Comment: so what you need is, you want to be able to change the direction and speed of the rotating circle (in your path) with your fingers?

Comment: yes, be able to move it freely on the path with your finger but being limited to only move in a circular trail.

Comment: I know this is an old post, I was wondering if you found a solution for it.